# Is it possible to do a wildcard search in spotlight in iOS 10.X?

Tags: ios, spotlight, search

I want to search for a specific app (example of Instaflash) on my iPhone or iPad but only remember part of its name. In this example 'flash' being the search term inputted into spotlight in iOS 10.X on my iPhone or iPad. Can search terms somehow be used with a wild card option? Something like *flash* to obtain a list of possible results?

Answer (score 1):

They don't do wildcards, but flash would bring up anything that contains flash including flash at the beginning, end or middle of the word.  If you are talking about mid-wildcards like fl***light, then no, you cannot do that.

Comment: I would assume that typing 'flash' would show Instaflash as a result but it does not?

Comment: It should.  For example, a search of "mobile" on my device brings up Geico Mobile, T-Mobile Tuesdays, WW Mobile and BoA

Comment: I would assume there is no way to force spotlight to re index?

Comment: Yes there is, there's a few questions here that address that and a quick search should bring-up the relevant answers.